# What does [underscore-java] mean?

Tags: discussion, tags

I just stumbled over [underscore-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/underscore-java). I have no idea what this tag is about, but still there’s a dozen questioners who considered this tag appropriate for their question.

Can anyone shed some light on the purpose of this tag (and edit its wiki in the best case)?

Comment: Quick google search found this https://javadev.github.io/underscore-java/ Maybe some java expert can tell if this is a proper guess.

Comment: I found this Github [link](https://github.com/javadev/underscore-java) about it. Difficult for me to tell more.

Comment: Maybe that was the original intention, yet, it seems none of the questions tagged with it have that topic.

Comment: I had a look at all these questions. Only the first one seems related effectively to this Github page. But I am not an expert in java.

Comment: There are eleven questions and for more than *half*, I have absolutely no idea why that tag was even chosen. I'm being generous to the rest of the questions - one at least was asking something about underscores, another had dashes (which I guess is like a cousin of an underscore). But there is nothing to really justify the tag in most of the questions. None seems to mention the Underscore-java library, as far as I can see.

Comment: @VLAZ The first question (I guess the tag was created at that time) explicitly mentions this library. The only one effectively.

Comment: Maybe just put the link to the library in the tag description, remove the tag from all questions that have no connection to the library and see what happens next? If there is any other use for this tag, users will have to find out another name for it and maybe it will be more clear then.

Comment: @TadeuszKopec but is it worth keeping the tag at all, when it serves only a single question?

Comment: "*but is it worth keeping the tag at all, when it serves only a single question?*" I don't see why not. Most tags have only served one question at some point. Then were added to others. I don't see any harm in keeping the tag if it accurately describes the question.

Comment: Sounds to me like an implementation of the popular js library underscore for Java.   Underscore is an early functional programming library.

Comment: @VLAZ not exactly. Some tags were created by tagging already existing questions that were found to have something in common. But yes, it’s normal to create a tag with a single question and see whether it takes off. But when all it got over a year were wrongly tagged questions, it should be allowed to ask whether this tag should persist.

Comment: It could be a mistaken attempt to refer to https://underscorejs.org/ if any of the questions look like JavaScript instead of Java.

Comment: @VLAZ I think "if it accurately describes the question" is key here. It seems for majority of questions where it was chosen it does not.

Comment: @eis correct, [I agree with this already](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/404821/what-does-underscore-java-mean?noredirect=1#comment821751_404821). I was replying to whether it's worth keeping the tag on a single question: *in that context*, if the tag correctly describes the content of the question, I don't see harm in keeping it.

Comment: Agreed with the findings, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59466516/add-extra-metadata-while-converting-json-to-xml) is the only question that deserves to have the tag and it is clearly about the mentioned Java library.

Comment: @Gimby I think the key is not how many *questions* the tag has, but how many *watchers* it has.  I'm willing to bet that for this tag the answer is zero, making it a good candidate for elimination.

Comment: @MarkRansom It was 47 watchers. But a good to ensure it doesn't get any more would be to eliminate it, I suppose.

Comment: @Scratte that means there are 47 people ready and willing to help if a legitimate question comes in under that tag.  I don't know why you would consider it a good thing to cut those people off.

Comment: @MarkRansom I think there was a misunderstanding. I don't think there is. I thought you were advocating for it to be removed :) But even it it didn't have any, I'm not sure that no watchers means it's to be eliminated. Watchers could come. If the tag has meaning, I don't see how it's relevant.

Comment: @Scratte it's relevant because each of the watchers believes the tag has meaning.  I was only advocating for the tag to be removed if it had no watchers; I'm surprised there are so many.

Comment: @TylerH That was my first thought as well, but I didn't see any that (obviously) related to underscore.js either.

Comment: @Cody Gray Even moderators should express their opinions in comments or answers, not by editing a question. As far as I know, other tags were burninated when no-one could give a clear guideline of when to use it or what it actually means. I might be wrong about it and of course, I might be the only one not seeing its purpose, that’s what the question is about. You may tell the world your opinion about in a comment or answer, but  not by editing the question.

Comment: Every Meta question about tags only strengthens my belief that the current rep gate for tag creation is completely ineffective at preventing bad tags from being created.

Comment: @IanKemp I have the same feeling. I think, providing a description should be mandatory, as when even the creator can’t explain the purpose of a tag, its creation is more than questionable. And low quality tag explanations should go the same route as other posts, including a tag creation ban for those who flood the site with bad tags.

Comment: The presence of that line is the difference between this question being on-topic or off-topic. I thought you'd prefer to have the question edited to be on-topic, rather than me having to close it as off-topic because you did not meet the minimum requirements for a burnination proposal. Speaking of not meeting the minimum requirements, "We do not burninate tags because they are unclear" does not meet the minimum requirements for an answer, so no, that would not have been appropriate for an answer. Tags should never be burninated just because you don't know what they mean. It isn't an opinion.

Comment: @CodyGray I did not suggest to burninate it, I asked if *anyone* can tell what it means **or** whether it is a burnination candidate (*in case no-one can tell what it means*). That’s not connected to my person at all. You should have noticed that this question was tagged with `[discussion]`, not with `[burninate-request]`. The discussion could have caused a new burnination proposal but since answers were given about the supposed meaning (and there even was a question matching the tag out of the dozen), it is not. So it was answerable. Don’t get triggered by a single word, read and understand.

Comment: It isn't only me I'm worried about.

Answer (score 8):

As @Damien points out in the comment, it seems pretty clear that this tag was created to categorize questions related to a Java library on GitHub named “underscore-java” (https://github.com/javadev/underscore-java).  As it is unclear why the later questions chose to associate this tag, it seems to make sense to assume that this tag means “pertains to the underscore-java library”.

Comment: From that page: "Underscore-java is a java port of Underscore.js."

Answer (score 3):

The tag was originally created for the Java port of the underscore.js JavaScript library, but unfortunately it has been misappropriated for questions about the actual JavaScript library, because users don't read.

In more positive news, I've updated the tag's usage guidance and wiki - both to call out its proper usage, and to discourage users who do read from incorrectly applying it.

Comment: “because users don't read” But what should the users read when there was no tag description? But anyway, when I stumbled over the tag, it was a question that was not even remotely connected to neither of the libraries and that seemed to be the case for most questions with that tag. They were not about the JavaScript library either. They had nothing in common.

Comment: But I appreciate the attempt to make something useful out of the tag and looked for questions actually being about underscore-java to tag them appropriately.

Answer (score -3):

I believe this tag was actually created by mistake and was intended for JavaScript instead as there is a very popular library (years ago now), called [Underscore.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underscore.js) that provides functional programming helpers, so many developers would be including it in their applications as a general-purpose library.

See: https://underscorejs.org/

Comment: It seems clear to me, and per the comments, others, that the tag was created for the the first/oldest question tagged with it.  That question explicitly links to a Java library named [underscore-java](https://github.com/javadev/underscore-java).  Given this, what sense does it make to think that the creation of the tag was a mistake?

Comment: Iy very well ciuld not have been a mistake but underscore-java is a mirror of the js library intended for java which has since gotten many of these features. Im still quite new so when i clicked on the tag and saw no questions currently tagged with it I thought the previous questions were no longer marked with it. My apologies for any confusion caused there of course.